# Verify Google App Engine Domain for Push Notifications

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am currently trying to get push notifications from Google working to my domain in Google App Engine. I use this guide: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push

The guide says that I should verify my domain to ensure that I own it. This should be done by uploading a html file to my app engine. Should this be needed if the domain is contained in Google App Engine?

What would be a convenient way to achieve this? Can I upload the html in a simple way? Right now I am just using the Google App Engine to host a Java servlet that exposes REST services.

Comment: Just follow instruction stated in the [verification method through HTML file upload](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179). You'll be using an HTML verification file to prove the site is yours.

Comment: just do it, if you don't want to upload a file, you might choose the DNS verification option which is easier